# Как устроен генератор звуков?

Tags: алгоритм, аудио, pyaudio

захотелось сделать свою программу для генерации рандомных звуковых эффектов, по типу bfxr, конечно же добавить своих фич и функций, расскажите как это устроено и как вообще работает там рандом (только алгоритм, генерацию звука из массивов я знаю как делать)